# Thread pool with only one active thread at a time and yielding inside a task to let another thread run

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I need a thread pool that executes only one task at a time and when a task calls a special method (let's call it `checkpoint` or `yield`), then:

- pause current thread
- try to find and resume another thread that is paused for too long
- if not found, resume another thread with the highest priority of its task

My tasks are waiting for the data from a socket most of the time, so `Thread.setPriority()` won't do.

For now I wrote a possible wrapper around what seek:

```
static final int READ_AHEAD_NUM = 5;

public String getFile(int fileId) {
    ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>(READ_AHEAD_NUM);
    MyDownloadJob[] jobs = new MyDownloadJob[READ_AHEAD_NUM];
    for (int i = 0; i < READ_AHEAD_NUM; i++) {
        urls.add("http://.../" + (fileId++));
    }
    // reprioritize and cancel unneeded jobs
    for (MyDownloadJob job : scheduler.getJobs()) {
        int index = urls.indexOf(job.getUrl());
        if (index == -1) {
            job.cancel();
        } else {
            jobs[index] = job;
            job.setPriority(index);
        }
    }
    MyDownloadJob job;
    // create missing jobs
    for (int index = 0; index < READ_AHEAD_NUM; index++) {
        if (jobs[index] == null) {
            jobs[index] = job = scheduler.addJob(new MyDownloadJobImpl(urls.get(index)));
            job.setPriority(index);
        }
    }

    // wait 1st job
    job = jobs[0];
    job.join();
    return job.getPath();
}

static abstract class MyDownloadJob extends Job {
    public abstract String getPath();
    public abstract String getUrl();

    private void checkpoint(int workAmount) throws Exception {
        if (super.yieldAndTestCancel(workAmount))
            throw new Exception("cancelled");
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        checkpoint(0);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(getPath());
        InputStream in = MyUtils.openConnection(getUrl());
        checkpoint(0);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            checkpoint(len);
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        for(;;) {
            break;
        }
        in.close();
        fos.close();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? At the moment, this could be homework and you haven't shown any effort yet.

Comment: Does googling count as an effort?

Comment: Yes, if the results are visible to the reader. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a thread pool with as many threads as reasonable. Then, inside your worker use a semaphore common to all threads, created outside via
final Semaphore threadExecution = new Semaphore(1)

Inside you can control execution via aquire() and release() on that semaphore.

Comment: but a semaphore will release a random thread, not the one I choose. Maybe I should use multiple lock objects, one per thread?

Comment: Semaphore has a fairness parameter, ensuring that the threads are executed in FIFO order - so I would not call that random. Apart from that: if you like to have perfect control over execution and only one thread is executing at the same time, then I am wondering why you use Concurrency/Threads at all?! A simple timer based single threaded code would also be an option.

Answer (score 0):

I see two approaches:

1. Use one thread per job: Whenever a thread wants to yield to another thread, it picks one from the list of threads, gives it a nudge and then waits itself to get awoken in turn. Take care that this means that (at least for a short time) two threads run at the same time and that it is possible that there is only one thread that tries to wake itself up.
2. Use one thread only: The single thread simply picks a job from the list and runs that job. When it wants suspend the current job and pick up another, it just stores its data and returns to the function that picks a job from the list of available jobs. The problem here is that you need to structure your job handler so that it can store its current state and pick up there later, with the first approach the "current state" is just the stack of the thread, which is typically easier.

Note that the algorithm to pick a job (by wait time of some priority) is completely independent thereof, so a kind of priority queue should work.